# Scale Image to image view

Tags: swift, interface-builder, xcode6

I am currently building an iOS app. I'm still in the very beginner stage but know my way around programming.

However the Interface Builder gives me a headache.

I want to have an image view and then programatically load the image content (no problem here). However I want the image view never to change the initial size (now matter what the resolution of the image is).

Here is the trick though: The image view should be a certain distance from the left, right and top. On the bottom the imageview needs to keep a minimum distance but can be as large as possible (for different iPhones).

I am still lost what mode I need to set for the imageview, because currently every single setting resizes the view somehow.

Anybody got any advice on how to set the mode and the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `windowWillResize` (or the live variant) from `NSWindowDelegate` and calculate the scale for the image in the view before re-displaying it.